# Yet another question about the pronunciation of the letter i

Tags: grammar

First, let's not talk about the long i (as in the name of the letter) or the short i (as in 'incorrect') pronunciations. This question is about the third and usually not talked about pronunciation - the ee sound (as in "pronunciation"). I have looked at many web sites about the letter i and none talk about the ee sound of the letter i. Why?

Would you call it the 'soft' letter i? As in the long A, short A and soft A? Do we also have long I, short I and soft I?

If one is teaching letter pronunciation to a non-english speaker all 3 sounds of the letter I have to be included. I don't see how it can be lumped into the letter e or letter y conversation. After all, it's an "i", not an "e" or "y".

thanks for any insight you can provide.
Chip

Comment: The _long i_ is actually a diphthong, /ai/, and the vowel at the beginning of _incorrect_ is /i/. Where are you getting these long, short and soft conventions from?

Comment: @jimsug It is insufficient as a professional simply to look upon an amateur with disdain. An answer to his very interesting question might have been more helpful.

Comment: @ws2 I apologise if my comment seemed disdainful, but I'm actually, earnestly asking where he's getting this terminology from? How else can I answer the question, when he specifically asks for one in reference to the long/short/soft A. **user3569704** please don't interpret this as my being disdainful - I want to know what you're being taught so that I can help.

Comment: Also, could you provide the details for which variant of English (American, British, Canadian, etc) you're trying to learn? In the case of vowels, this is particularly important.

Comment: This is western US American english. There are 3 sounds for the letter i - pie, ski, twitter. I only mentioned the long/short/soft A as a reference, is there similar references for the letter i? is the sound of i in ski considered soft?
--
Chip

Comment: @user3569704: what you call the "ee sound" is actually the original "long i sound", before the Great Vowel Shift. English spelling was designed for Middle English and never changed, even though the vowels did. As an American, you were probly taught Webster's "long i" and "short i" for _like_ and _lick_. That's phonetically wrong, and it's all based on the extremely false presupposition -- which your questions demonstrates you hold -- that pronunciation comes from spelling letters. Wrong-o! Spelling letters try and fail to encode the pronunciation, which is real. Spelling is just a bad code.

Comment: I appreciate the info, but it still comes down to this one fact: the letter "i" has the "ee" sound. Period. There's no arguing that fact. It is what it is. When teaching a person who knows no english at all the letter "a", for example, we tell them it has 3 sounds. When teaching them the letter "e" we tell them it has two sounds. But the letter "i" which obviously has 3 sounds - we tell them it has only 2 sounds? and ignore the third? When teaching absolute beginners they don't care about, and don't need to hear about, dipthongs and old english/middle english, etc.They just need to know how to

Comment: pronounce english words - ski (skee), broccoli (brah-cohl-lee), etc. The rest is just too advanced for an beginning english learner.

Comment: Unfortunately, the English language is absolutely _not_ phonetic, so it is difficult to transcribe sounds accurately with the English  alphabet itself. However, these nuanced sounds (or, more accurately, _[phonemes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phoneme)_) can be accurately written with [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). The phonemes for _long_, _short_, and _soft "I"_ are respectively /aɪ/, /ɪ/, and /iː/ (none of them are "incorrect", they are just used in different contexts). Use Oxford Learner's Dictionary (online) to hear pronunciation.

Comment: For an approximation with Spanish phonology, the long "I" /aɪ/ sound is the same as the Spanish _aire_ /aɪre/; the soft "I" sound /iː/ is the same as the Spanish _mío_ /miːo/. Unfortunately, I do not know a Spanish word with the short "I" sound /ɪ/. (Your profile stated that you are from Colombia, so I am assuming you are fluent in Spanish.)

Comment: @user3569704: Your phrase _the letter "i" has the "ee" sound_ is where you make the big mistake. **Letters do not "have" sounds.** There are thirteen vowel sounds in English, and none of them are spelled consistently by using the 5 English "vowel letters". All of the vowel letters in English are used inconsistently, all the time. Starting with the spelling **always** causes confusion; [starting with the sounds](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf) is much more satisfying.

Comment: OK, I will take another look at the process I am using. As for myself being in Colombia, I live here, but am from the US, from Arizona and Washington. I am not yet very good with spanish, but am learning at the same time as teaching english to beginners, mostly absolute beginners.

Comment: I don't know how much freedom you have in your teaching, but I would earnestly suggest that you start by ignoring the letters, and teach them the sounds of English. When they have got those clear, then you can introduce them to the bizarre and messy way we write those sounds.

Comment: The question is: which alternative is more confusing? Telling students that sometimes "i" makes the "long e" sound, or telling students about a "soft i" and a "long e" sound, and then telling them that these are the same sound? You're not going to get away from confusing; English spelling ***is*** confusing. And "i" isn't even the most confusing vowel; "u" makes four sounds: "cuckoo", "cute", "cut", and "put".

Answer (score 1):

As a non-native speaker, I was taught that English has:

- a **short i** (as in *ship* /ʃɪp/) (or as in *incorrect* /ɪnkəˈrɛkt/)
- a **long i** (as in *sheep* /ʃiːp/) (or as in *e* /iː/)

I was also told that the difference between these two sounds is not just the length of the sound.

The phonetic transcription of the word **"pronunciation"** /prəˌnʌnsɪˈeɪʃ(ə)n/ can be found in the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pronunciation?q=pronunciation).

I imagine your question refers to the sounds in /sɪˈeɪ/. The apostrophe tells us that there are two syllables in /sɪˈeɪ/ and that the second one is stressed /eɪ/. The first syllable /sɪ/ contains a short-i sound, whereas the second syllable /eɪ/ is a diphthong.

A [diphthong](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/diphthong?q=diphthong) is *"a sound formed by the combination of two vowels in a single syllable, in which the sound begins as one vowel and moves towards another (as in coin, loud, and side)"*.

Thus, to answer the OP's original question, one could say that this *"soft-i"* sound is better understood as part of a diphthong (that is, the result of combining a short-i sound with another vowel).

---

**UPDATE**

It has been pointed out in the comments that [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pronunciation) reports an alternative pronunciation for American English: /prə-ˌnən(t)-sē-ˈā-shən/. Although the phonetic notation used in the Merriam-Webster dictionary (see [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/pronsymbols.html)) doesn't make this apparent, it is still possible to understand the sound /ā/ as a diphthong that starts with a sound /e/ and moves towards a short-i sound /ē/.

For those, like me, that aren't familiar with the phonetic notation used in the Merriam-Webster dictionary, here's a list of sounds and diphthongs relevant to this question:

**long i**

- /ā/ a in ace
- /'ē/ ea in easy
- /,ē/ y in easy

**short i**

- /i/ i in hit
- /ˈī/ i in ice
- /ȯi/ oy in boy

**semivowel y**

- /y/ y in yet
- /yü/ you in youth
- /yu̇r/ u in curable

Comment: In American English (which is what the OP speaks), *pronunciation* is usually pronounced with /siˈeɪ/, not /sɪˈeɪ/.  See [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pronunciation), where it's the only alternative listed. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm checking the link to M-W, but I can't find a description of their phonetic notation. I see that in AmE there isn't a dyphthong in /sē-ˈā/, but I can't find a description of what /ē/ stands for.

Comment: In M-W, ē means /i:/, and /ā/ means /eɪ/. There's a key somewhere online, but it's hard to find and I don't have much time right now.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/pronsymbols.html